# PrimeReact Tree - Drag and Drop

Tags: tree, drag-and-drop, primereact

I use PrimeReact tree and they implement the ability to drag and drop in the same tree.
I want that during mouse move I will be able to check if it's ok to drop the item or not and if it's not ok to change the cursor to 'none' or something like that.
In the following code I succeeded to check if it's ok or not to drop the item I drag but I can't change the cursor the effectAllowed stay as initialize in the onDragStart and can't change during mouse move.

this is what I tried:

```
const handleDragOver = (event, node) => {
    if (node.key !== selectedItem.key && lastDragOverKey != node.key) {
      const isValid = isPasteValid(selectedItem, node);
      event.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = isValid ? "copy" : "none";
      setLastDragOverKey(node.key);
    }
  };
```

Can anyone know how to do it? How to change the cursor during the run.